# Netlogo turtle skips specific patch

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to instruct turtles to visit all green patches.

There is a behavior which I can't get my head around: patch 0,0 is always avoided if the location of origin = center (see screenshot with 0,0 colored blue), and the lower left corner if location of origin = corner.

[image]

Why is this? What error am I making here?

```
;;==========================================================
globals [
  memory
  target
]
patches-own [visit-counter]

;;==========================================================
to setup
  ca
  resize-world -6 6 -6 6
  set-patch-size 40
  create-turtles 1 [
    set memory (list patch-here)
    setxy random-pxcor random-pycor
    set size 1
    set color blue
  ]

  ask patches [if random 100 < 40 [set pcolor green]]
  ask patch 0 0 [set pcolor green]

  ask patches [set visit-counter 0]  
  reset-ticks
end

;;==============================================

to go

  ask turtles [choose-target]
  tick
  if ticks > 500 [stop]
end

;;==============================================
to choose-target
  pd

  ;; set of unvisited patches
  let unvisited patches with [not member? self [memory] of myself]

  ;; set of green patches that are not visited
  let targets patches with [(member? self unvisited) and (pcolor = green)]

  ;; select target and move there
  set target one-of targets with-min [distance myself]

  ifelse target != nobody [
    face target
    fd 1
    set visit-counter (visit-counter + 1)
    set memory lput patch-here memory
  ]
  [die
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initialise the variable 'memory', you have `set memory (list patch-here)`. At that point, the turtle is sitting on `patch 0 0`, so the origin patch is in the memory. Your code for finding targets excludes those already in the memory `let unvisited patches with [not member? self [memory] of myself]`. It is therefore ineligible to be chosen as a target.

Comment: Thanks! I see that point, but why does it occur only on patch 0,0?

Comment: When you create a turtle without specifying a location, it is created on patch 0 0 (actually at xcor = 0, ycor = 0), so patch 0 0 is always `patch-here` at the start.